# Apache server rewrite special characters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, special-characters

I have web page with references using (#) special character. How to make Rewrite rule which will preserve the character.

For example: i have 'domain/test' and i need to redirect this to 'domain/#test2'

If i use:

**RewriteRule ^/domain/test/$ /domain/#test2**

The # sign is encoded as %23 and i get 404 not found. I tried to escape it with '' then use {ESCAPE:#} but nothing works, all of the characters are encoded.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should try using the [NE] flag: RewriteRule ^/domain/test/$ /domain/#test2 [NE] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: I am trying that all day, [B,NE] also, but i still get %23. Should i enable something before?
Maye add AllowEncodedSlashes On. What is the proper way of using this, where i need to place it.

Comment: @LukaszZagroba actually what worked is [NE,R] as in the example, so thanks :)